# How to style specific option in a drop down while the values are loading dynamically (PrimeNG)?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

Like title says I need to set `style: color: red;` in some options from a drop down list and I don't know how.
Here is my code (I'm using PrimeNG):

My HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <form [formGroup]="reasonForm" #reasonModal="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onReject()">
   <div formArrayName="items">
     <div *ngFor="let item of Items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="rejectionreasons row">
       <div class="col">
        <p>{{'Select fields for rejection' | translate}}:</p>
        <p-multiSelect [maxSelectedLabels]="5" [options]="dataListReject"
          defaultLabel="{{'Select' | translate}}..." [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
          formControlName="datatoreject">
        </p-multiSelect>
       </div>
       <div class="col">
        <p>{{'Select rejection reason' | translate}}:</p>
        <p-dropdown [options]="rejectionReasons" formControlName="rejectionreason">
        </p-dropdown>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="button addrejection" (click)="deleteItem(i)">
         <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    ....
```

Here is a picture of how I want it to look like:
[image: drop down list]
And the HTML(Source page) that is generated:

```
<p-multiselectitem class="ng-tns-c4-6 ng-star-inserted" style="">
 <li class="ui-multiselect-item ui-corner-all" aria-label="First Name" 
  tabindex="0" style="display: block;">
  <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
   <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <span class="ng-star-inserted">First Name</span>
  <!---->
 </li>
</p-multiselectitem>
<p-multiselectitem class="ng-tns-c4-6 ng-star-inserted" style="">
 <li class="ui-multiselect-item ui-corner-all" aria-label="Surname" 
  tabindex="0" style="display: block;">
  <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
   <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <span class="ng-star-inserted">Surname</span>
  <!---->
 </li>
</p-multiselectitem>
<p-multiselectitem class="ng-tns-c4-6 ng-star-inserted" style="">
 ....
</p-multiselectitem>
```

The tricky part I think here is that the list is loading dynamically and i don't have always the same values and I want to style specific values when they appear in this drop down list. Any ideas?

Comment: [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: @Maryannah I don't understand exactly what's your point

Comment: It explains how to style external components.

Comment: @Maryannah yeah but i need to style specific words from the list and not create a css rule for html tags inside the list, otherwise they will all be included in this style.

Comment: And to do that, you need to select the words through a CSS selector and use the deep selectors to apply the styles to the concerned items. Is that right ?

Comment: I uploaded the html code if that helps. I can't figure it out...

Comment: I don't get your issue : do you not know how to apply classes to specific items of a list, or do you not know how to apply a css style to an external component (here, primeNG) ?

Comment: The first one I assume.

Comment: Oh, okay ! So what are the fields to "red" ? Do you have specific conditions to find them ?

Comment: Nope all the html tags are the same. The only thing that is different is the value inside the `<span>` tags and the `arial-label` as I can see now. These values are loaded from a local mock up.

Comment: Okay but how does this `aria-label` tage **knows** that those ones must be different ?

Comment: I don't know I just "import" in the primeng multiselect a list with an object with values and labels and insert it in the `[options]="dataListReject"`.